# Access Kubernetes API from container within Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

- I launched a pod on a minikube "cluster":

Yaml:

```
---
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: orchestration

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: orchestration
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: orchestration
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: orchestration
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: orchestration
    namespace: default

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: orchestration-master
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: orchestration
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: orchestration
      containers:
        - name: orchestration
          image: joan38/orchestration:latest
          ports:
            - name: ui
              containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orchestration-ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: orchestration
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 31010
      targetPort: 8080
```

- Connect on the pod: `kubectl exec -ti --namespace default myContainer bash`
- Query the API: `curl -k https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1`
- Result in an `Unauthorized`

Why? How can I auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials for the service account are mounted at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`

```
curl https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local/api/v1 \
  --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(</var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)"
```